# Can't reach a local website through apache in a docker container (windows & docker toolbox)

Tags: php, windows, apache, docker, dockerfile

I built a Docker image with apache2 and a little configuration in order to run a local web server on windows.

Here is the Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:5.6.15-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
apt-utils vim git php5-mysql php5-memcache php5-memcached php5-intl \
sendmail aptitude wget
RUN apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef"
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER test
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

EXPOSE 80

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

In apache-config.conf, I just have a little virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.loc
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

  <Directory /var/www/html/test/>
      Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In my /c/Users/public/sites/test folder, I just have an index.php file with the following code in it :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

I built my image with this command in Docker Quickstart Terminal

```
docker build -t php56 .
```

Then I built my container :

```
docker run --name=php56_container -t --rm -v "//c/Users/Public/sites:/var/www/html" -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 php56
```

The container is well created but I get the following message :

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2.
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2.
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Mon Dec 21 14:18:24.968215 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 21 14:18:24.968982 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '
```

**My problem is that I can't access my test website and I don't know why.**

I tried to add the "ServerName 172.17.0.2" directive in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but when I restart apache2 service, it stops my container from running.

I tried to inspect my container to see its ip, but sometimes it doesn't have one sometimes it's 172.17.0.2

I tried the following adresses in my browser but I can't reach anything :

http://test.loc

172.17.0.2:80

0.0.0.0:80

**Does someone knows how to run a webserver with Docker on windows and reaching a site with his Servername ? (test.loc)**

Answer (score 3):

something you need to know is that when you run docker on windows its not actual running on your windows machine but the docker toolbox creates a virtual box VM in wich it runs docker. You can read more on this here https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/
so you can check your website on the ip the virtual box VM has.
To find out the ip address of the vm you can use the following command

```
docker-machine ip
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I managed to get the list of the machines with docker-machine ls and then to reach my website with the ip. But is there a way to determine only one time the ip address in order to write it in the virtual hosts ?

Comment: you don’t need the ip address in the virtual host. in the spirit of "the docker way" software in containers and the containers themselves should run on every docker host. they should net be dependant in any way on the ip of the host.

Comment: I mean, if I want to reach my local website with the test.loc ServerName, I need the IP of the machine to put in the VirtualHost. Do I have a way to determine myself the ip of the machine to pre insert it in the virtual host and to be sure it won't change ?

Comment: to do that you could assign a static ip to the virtaulbox and edit your hosts file to map that ip to test/loc i find virtual box netwerking to be tricky sometimes and i dont know how the docker toolbox would react. more info on ssh'ing into the virtual box is at the bottom of this page https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/ and setting netwerking in(most) linux os is here
http://askubuntu.com/questions/470237/assigning-a-static-ip-to-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

Add this row on Dockerfile

```
RUN echo "ServerName www.example.com" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```